# One DeviceContext per Material?

Tags: directx11, metal

In D3D11, we have a DeviceContext, which represents the Renderpipeline.

In Metal, we have a RenderPipelineState.
In Metal, I cache the RenderPipelineState, it is the abstraction of a "material".

Is DeviceContext in D3D11 the same? I.e. 1 DeviceContext = "1 Material" or do I set the DeviceContext (BlendState,DepthState) whenever the Material changes?
My idea was to have a Material Class which holds a pointer to a DeviceContext and whenever i want to draw this material, i execute Draw*() on this context.

Answer (score 2):

A device context is just an interface that allows you to issue commands to the GPU. It doesn't hold any internal state, and therefore it doesn't represent any 'RenderPipelineState'. Moreover, looking at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-intro (and other tutorial), it appears that the only use of multiple context is with multithreading (where each thread has its own context, immediate or deferred).

What you can do is (as once I did), build your own RenderPipelineState, which holds pointers to the resources needed (shaders, textures, ...) and has the method "set" (or draw). On top of this I'd build a RenderPipelineStateManager which holds pointers/id of the current resources active at a given time, in this way you can check wherever you actually need to set that resource or not (reducing overhead) as, if I rembember correctly, is not done DirectX side (e.g. if your current vertex shader is VS_1 and in your next material you still use VS_1 and call context->VSSetShader(VS_1) it will result in a driver call to change the shader as if it was a new one).

Something like this:

```
class RenderPipelineState {
    VShader* _vs;
    PShader* _ps;
    BlendState* _bs;
    ...
}

class RenderPipelineStateManager {
    Context* _ctx;
    VShader* _ActiveVs;
    PShader* _ActivePs;
    BlendState* _ActiveBs;
    ...

    void set(RenderPipelineState* _rps) {
        if (_rps->_vs != _ActiveVs) {
            _ctx->VSSetShader(_rps->_vs);
            _ActiveVs = _rps->_vs;
        }
        ...
    }
}

class Material {
    RenderPipelineState* _material;

    void apply(RenderPipelineStateManager* _mng) {
        _mng->set(_material);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another related question. How would you bind Material Parameters (Textures,Constant Buffers) with your approach?

Comment: Mmh, the same way you bind shaders? I'm not sure I understood your question

Comment: From a Class structure perspective, where should this binding happen?

Comment: There are many ways to structure it. One is to bind every resource inside a RenderPipelineState inside RederPipelineStateManager::set. Of course you'll probably need more parameters when binding (such as the target slot). You can save this extra data inside each resource class when needed. And inside set do: if rps->resource != activeResource then rps->resource->bind(). This for each resource you have in your RenderPipelineState. You may use vector if you have more resource of the same type, or use virtual methods if you face situations where some materials require extra logic, and so on...